# MYSQL multiply column value by value in previous row

Tags: mysql

I hope I can phrase this properly - I'm not sure I've been approaching this correctly.

I am running a `MySQLi` query for which I need to order the results by the result of a sum (multiplicaiton) of the values in one column. The values are to 2 decimal places and are 'odds' for sporting results. As Such i can not simply sum the values from each row as the result (e.g. 1,1,1 adds to 3 but multiplies to 1) does not give me 'correct' ordering.

At present i am simply performing a sum in my query

```
SUM(Fav_odds) AS Total
```

But i'm stumped how i can get '`Total`' to be the result of '`Fav_odds` * number of rows' in my query.

```
Fav_odds | Vendor
------------------
1.2      | Name
2.1      | Name  
3.2      | Name
```

So for Vendor called 'Name' i would like to give a multipled value for items in Fav_odds column (e.g. 1.2 * 2.1 * 3.2 = 8.064)

Comment: You really need to explain this better.  The more I read it, the more confusing it gets.  Explain what you want to do, without reference to the data structures, and then separately tell us the data structures you have in place.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Or maybe give a small limited set of values, 5 or 6, and the expected result out of them.  Show the values first, and then separately show the expected output.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am trying to get the total value of a column when it is multiplied again and again by the next number that appears in the same column, but on the next row. E.g. the values in column 1 may be 1.2 on one row, 2.1 on the next row and 1.3 on the last, i would like my query to give (1.2 * 2.1 * 1.3). Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select round(EXP(SUM(LOG(fav_odds))),3) as fav_odds from table;
```

Comment: Superb, absolutely perfect, thank you so much for taking the time out to help. How does this work?

Comment: Could you please explain, how this works?

Answer (score 2):

use a variable

```
set @miller := 1;
select orderingTotal from
    (select @miller:=@miller*Fav_odds as orderingTotal
       from mytable) mytotaltable
order by orderingTotal;
```

or it could be a matter of just saying

```
sum(Fav_odds) * count(Fav_odds)
```

if what you are saying at the end is the right way ("fav_total * the number of rows").

Comment: Thank you, i have added a small sample of the database in the question

Comment: Thank you for helping, i'm sorry my description was not accurate enough, it has been  answered now